# Combination without repetition

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

I have Collection `List<Car>`.

How to compare each item from this collection with rest without repeatition.

Ex:

1. iteration:

this car is Audi and secondCar is BMW

```
bool IsSimilar(Car secondCar)
{
  if(this.Name==secondCar.Name) return true;
  return false;
}
```

this is not permitted:

n iteration

this car is BMW and secondCar is Audi

```
bool IsSimilar(Car secondCar)
{
  if(this.Name==secondCar.Name) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Clearer:

```
List<Car> car=new List<Car>();
List<Pair> pairs=new List<Pair>();
pairs.Cars=new List<Car>();

foreach(Car car in cars)
{
  foreach(Car secondCar in cars)
  {
    if(secondCar!=car)
    {
      if(car.Name==secondCar.name && car.Owner==secondCar.Owner)
      {
        Pair pair=new Pair();
        pair.Cars.Add(car);
        pair.Cars.Add(secondCar);
        pairs.Add(pair);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just don't want to compare cars twice(you know first iteration compare car 1 with car2, next  car2 is base car and car1 is secondCar)

Sorry for my terrible English

Comment: Not sure what you want. Can you please explain what you mean by compare to (check for equality, sort it, ...). What sould the output be like and what do you expect as the output of the comparison.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.
Are you trying to create a sorted list with no repetitions? - If so have you tried using LINQ?

Comment: I wanna search for items that has the same properties. 

If i have 100 items, I wanna use method like this:

foreach(Car car in cars)
{
foreach(Car secondCar in cars)
{
if(secondCar!=car)
{
car1.IsSimilar(car2);
}
}
}

But without repetion, so if I compared car 1 with car2 before I don's wanna do it again. 

Method IsSimilar will not return bool, but do something like:

List<Pair> pairs=new List(Pair) <-this is out method


this is in method:

Pair pair=new Pair();
pair.Items.Add(car1);
pair.Items.Add(secondCar);

Comment: Maybe naming it combination wasn't good idea...it introduced mess...

Comment: I don't wanna change collection Cars

Comment: First question - if Car1 is similar to Car2, and Car2 is similar to Car3, then does it necessarily mean that Car1 is similar to Car3, or not?

Comment: Also - if Car1 is similar to Car3, then does it necessarily mean that Car3 is similar to Car1, or not?

Comment: if Car1 is similar to Car3, then does it necessarily mean that Car3 is similar to Car1 -yes, that right.

if Car1 is similar to Car2, and Car2 is similar to Car3, then does it necessarily mean that Car1 is similar to Car3, or not - possible yes. But it will be to manual resolved(In GUI by user). But at the end car 1, car2 and car will fall into the same Pair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't loop over the collection, loop over the indices

```
for (i = 0; i < length(cars); i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < length(cars); j++) {
        <do comparison>
    }
}
```

Comment: no, it is not this.

Look:

i=0, and j=1

we have car1 and car2.

i=1, and j=0

we have car2 and car 1.

I don't wanna repeat the same job(checking properties of object, because it has done in previous iteration)

Comment: when i = 1, j will start from i + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2, so you won't compare things twice. j will never be 0 when i = 1.

Comment: @phenevo, using sirlark's method you could never have i=1 and j=0 because j always starts 1 higher than the current value of i.

Comment: yeah, sorry (coffe was ended yesterday :) )

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to get unique combinations from a list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
        // perform operation
```

Comment: no, it is not this.

Look:

i=0, and j=1

we have car1 and car2.

i=1, and j=0

we have car2 and car 1.

I don't wanna repeat the same job(checking properties of object, because it has done in previous iteration)

Comment: @phenevo: When i=1, j will start at 2 and will never be 0.  That's the point.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to repeat what others have said and explain your comments to them (which was erroneous):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
        <do something>
    }
}
```

You commented about this technique that "*no, it is not this. Look: i=0, and j=1 we have [...]. i=1, and j=0 we have [...]*".

What you have missed is that `j` always starts from `i+1`. So it will **never** be the case that `i=1 and j=0` as you mentioned!